# Links not working if current url doesn't end with "/" (slash)

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, hyperlink

I am currently experiencing very strange behavior.

If my url doesn't end with slash, all links are broken. Specifically, if my url is "http://localhost:8080/SharedTodoListDemo/todolist", then this code

```
<a href="delete" class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message code="todolist.button.delete"/></a>
```

redirects to "http://localhost:8080/SharedTodoListDemo/delete"

If my url is instead "http://localhost:8080/SharedTodoListDemo/todolist/"

then the same code redirects (correctly) to "http://localhost:8080/SharedTodoListDemo/todolist/delete"

Do you have any ideas why this might be happening and what to do about it? I am using Spring + Spring MVC and need to link uniformly in order to be able to map to controller methods.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've also tried **href="/delete"** and **href="./delete"**. The first redirects even more strangely to "http://localhost:8080/delete" both with and without the backslash in url, the second works the same as above.

Comment: Unfortunately it's no good. In case it ends with slash, it becoems either http://localhost:8080/SharedTodoListDemo/todolist/todoList/delete (todoList/delete) or http://localhost:8080/todoList/delete (/todoList/delete)

Comment: Don't use a relative url.

Comment: Try `<a href="/SharedTodoListDemo/todolist/delete">`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a while I've solved it myself.

This does the trick:

```
<spring:url value="/product/new" var="springLink" />
<a href="${springLink}">spring link</a>
```

The above works in both cases (the original url ends or doesn't with slash).

Compare to these, which don't work:

```
<a href="new">my link</a>
<a href="/new">my link</a>
<a href="product/new">my link</a>
<a href="/product/new">my link</a>
```